# If $\phi$ is a propositional consequence of $\{ \gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n\}$ then $\Sigma \vdash ((\gamma_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\gamma_n)\to\phi)$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I am reading [A Friendly Introduction to Mathematical Logic](https://milneopentextbooks.org/download/friendly-intro-2e-update19-pdf/) by Christopher Leary and Lars Kristiansen. This is what I want to prove (and this is not in the textbook):

Let $\mathcal{L}$ be first order language. Let $\Gamma =\{ \gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n\}$ be a finite set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas and $\phi$ is an $\mathcal{L}$-formula. Suppose that $\phi$ is a propositional consequence of $\Gamma$. Then $\Sigma \vdash ((\gamma_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\gamma_n)\to\phi)$ for any set of $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\Sigma$.

It seems true to me however I can't seem to prove this.

Here's my attempt anyways:
Suppose that $\phi$ is a propositional consequence of $\{ \gamma_1,\ldots, \gamma_n\}$. So, $((\gamma_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\gamma_n)\to\phi)$ is valid, i.e., $\models (\gamma_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\gamma_n)\to\phi)$ and consequently,  $(\gamma_1\wedge\ldots\wedge\gamma_n)\models\phi$.

I cannot seem to proceed  any further. Any help or hint would be appreciated!

Comment: Isn't thus just completeness? Theorem 3.2.2 in that book.

Comment: @Magdiragdag It apparently is! I am studying Chapter 2 and was wondering how I can prove it. I was reading The Deduction Theorem (Theorem 2.7.4 in the textbook) and the authors' proof really is not convincing to me. I was wondering how to write down a step by step deduction of Rule PC which is in page 65 and I can't do it without proving my claim apparently. Can you take a look at it?

Comment: Does 'propositional consequence' really mean what you say it does in the question?

Comment: @Magdiragdag Yes, it does.

Comment: The definition of the rule PC is definition 2.4.5 on page 53. Note that $\Gamma$ can be empty in this definition. So any propositional tautology is effectively an axiom.

Comment: @RobArthan Thank you. That answers the question that I had.